# Where do I find the Spotify auth.js script?

Tags: facebook, spotify

I'm trying to use Spotify's auth.authenticateWithFacebook API and am getting the following error in the console log:

Uncaught Error: Failed to read "sp://import/scripts/api/auth.js"

This occurs when the following is execute:

```
var auth = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/auth');
```

Is the auth module public yet?

I am trying this as a result of a response to "How do I connect my Spotify App to Facebook Connect?" where they suggest the use of the auth module.

I have downloaded the latest client preview with no difference.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Download the preview version from [this](http://developer.spotify.com/blog/archives/2012/01/12/new-spotify-api-preview-build-available/) post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old post, but in case anyone ends up here from a search engine or a related SO post, I'd just like to add that Facebook authentication has since been added to the API (version 1.x.). Please see [this page](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-auth-auth.html) for documentation around auth.